# setLayoutParams() method doesn't work in onLayout()

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-view

I tried to resize my Component in my extended LinearLayout.
in the Method onLayout().

```
public ExtLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
  super(context,attrs,0);
  init(attrs);
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {

  Log.d(TAG,
        "OnLayout1: Left: " + l + "Right: " + r + "Top: " + t + "Bottom: " + b + " children" + this.getChildCount() + " changed" + changed + " getHeight "
              + this.getMeasuredHeight() + " getWidth " + this.getMeasuredWidth());
  Child c = (SeedBar) this.getChildAt(0);
  c.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(20,this.getMeasuredHeight()-23));
  super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
}

private void init(AttributeSet attrs) {
  this.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
  this.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
  this.configureChild();
  this.invalidate();

}
private void configureChild() {
  Child c = new SeedBar(getContext());
  c.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(20, 100));
  this.addView(c, 0);
}
```

So I will add a Child and setUp the Size in the onLayout() Method, but nothing will happen.
The Child is extended from View

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by changing the layout within a layout process?

Comment: I will resize the Child to runtime, if I have more than one child in the Layout or the parentLayout will change the size. Do you understand?

Answer (score 1):

Despite being 5 years old and unanswered, this question is still the top search result on google for this problem. For anyone else trying to figure out this issue for custom components, you should not set LayoutParams on child views inside the parents onLayout(), it just doesn't work. Instead you want to call layout() on the child view

```
@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
  super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
  int margin = 4
  childView.layout(margin, margin, getWidth()-margin, getHeight()-margin)
}
```